# sign up/login using swift in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a project that requires to login and sign up, however I tried so many code methods and there is error.
Please I need someone to help me write those codes.
And yes i’m using Xcode software.

my problem is with **import Alamofire**
and I have no idea how to get the url address

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class Register: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let URL_USER_REGISTER = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signup: UIButton!

    @IBAction func signup(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //creating parameters for the post request
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "username":textFieldUsername.text!,
            "password":textFieldPassword.text!,
            "email":textFieldEmail.text!

        ]
    }
    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
    {
    response in
    //printing response
    print(response)

    //getting the json value from the server
    if let result = response.result.value {

    //converting it as NSDictionary
    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

    //displaying the message in label
    self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code and error you getting

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is for helping people with specific issues, not writing part of apps for them. Post your code, explain any issues or errors and we'll try to help work out what the fix is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //About : "I have no idea how to get the url address"

    //You need to know for sure where your service resource is.

    //about : let URL_USER_REGISTER = ""

    //You need to assign URL String of your service like  
    URL_USER_REGISTER = "https://yourwebsite.com/services/signup"

    and make URL from your service string like :

    let userRegisterUrl = URL(string: URL_USER_REGISTER)

    //Pass url in Alamofire request method like : 


    Alamofire.request(userRegisterUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        { 
//Your business logics...handle error,response,data in this block
    }
```